# Rspec test to request controller action but seems action wasn't executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, pry

I am new to Rails and Rspec and trying to write spec to test one non RESTful controller action.

Spec code:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ReportsController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET /full_members" do
    context "when current account doesn't have contacts" do
      let!(:current_account) { create(:account) }

      it "hit full_members action" do
        expect(get: '/reports/full_members').to be_routable

        expect(:get => "/reports/full_members").to route_to(
          controller: "reports",
          action: "full_members")

        get :full_members

      end
    end
  end
end
```

Controller code:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def full_members
    require "pry"
    binding.pry
    
    set_select_options_full_members
    @members = @current_account.contacts
  end
...
```

I was expecting to execute spec and stop at the breaking point pry. But the actual result is spec passed and pry didn't work.

```
Finished in 0.17359 seconds (files took 1.16 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

From rails routes I can see the route exists(the spec first two assertions also prove that)

```
~» rails routes | ag full_members                                                                     
>> full_members_reports GET    /reports/full_members(.:format)
```

My routes.rb

```
resources :reports, only: [:index] do
    collection do
      get 'full_members'
    end
end
```

Can not figure out why the pry didn't work in controller action. Can anyone help with that?  Thanks

Comment: The use of controller specs is greatly discouraged by both the Rails and RSpec teams as its a very flawed approach that mocks out the entire middleware stack.  ActionController::TestCase which is what controller specs wrap is depreciated. The modern way to test controllers is by integration and system tests (system, feature and request specs). https://everydayrails.com/2016/08/29/replace-rspec-controller-tests.html

Comment: @max thanks for the tips. I'll update the test and see if that works